# Error Analysis of Gaussian Interpolation

Tags: approximation-theory

Is there any theory available on how well I can approximate a function using a basis of Gaussians 
$$
\phi_k(x) = \exp(-\tfrac{x - x_k}{\lambda_k})
?
$$
I've heard a bit about [Gaussian process regression/Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging), which seems related, but the approach in the related literatur is very statistical and hence not what I am interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called approximation by [radial basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function). See Wendland's *Scattered Data Approximation* or Fasshauer's *Meshfree Approximation Methods With MATLAB*.